# Why doesn't .find() work with urllib.request.urlopen() in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to transition from urllib in python 2 to python 3. I can output the html source using .urlopen() but I can't index it using .find() method.

```
import urllib.request
fh = urllib.request.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com")
html = fh.read()
fh.close()

print(html.find("<p>"))
```

I get a type error. I understand that it's returning a byte-array but I'm pretty fuzzy about what that actually means. I've tried a few SO answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713183/basic-fetching-of-a-urls-html-body-with-python-3-x) which have been dead-ends. My question is:

Is there a straightforward, native method to get the page source of a URL as a string in python 3?

Comment: Why are you not using Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `html.decode('utf-8')` (or whatever encoding it happens to be) to get a `str` object that you can `.find()` on.

`.decode()` is used to take a flat set of bytes and transform them (via reversing a character encoding, such as UTF-8) into a string of actual codepoints (displayable symbols).

Comment: "whatever encoding it happens to be" is my issue. Why should I have to specify the encoding? Isn't that included in the document itself?

Comment: "Sometimes." Not all servers send Content-Encoding headers (and not everything you might fetch with `urlopen()` is text). Either way, `urlopen()` doesn't process them, it just gives you the raw result as a file-like object (which doesn't have encoding data associated with it).

Comment: However, I'd also second Ignacio's comment - using a library like BeautifulSoup would solve most of your issues, plus it's a better way to do HTML parsing.

Comment: No doubt. I've been trying to learn python and I guess I'm fixated on the problem of retrieving html as a string and haven't even considered parsing yet. I didn't realize that step was unnecessary.